# Netsuite Case query

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

Please can you assist me to figure out why the 1st line works but the next line does not

CASE WHEN {status}='Pending Fulfillment' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

CASE WHEN {status}='Pending Fulfillment' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END

The expression is true, but netsuite states the expression is wrong

As the first line gives out a different number I am confident the formula is correct but for some reason the characters are not being excepted

The expression is true, but netsuite states the expression is wrong - Have i formatted the text wrong? do i need brackets I dont understand how the figures work but the char format errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the formula type you are using.  The first expression will work with either `Formula(Numeric)` or `Formula(Text)` but the second will only work with `Formula(Text)`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The first one does work with a numeric formula. But the purpose is to convert the outcome to the string output. Which is number two

Comment: So make sure you have selected `Formula (Text)` in the Field column on the search Results tab.  If you have `Formula (Numeric)` selected when your formula returns text it will not work.